# How to detect location is settled iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, dictionary, core-location

I have an application that gets the users location and draws a polyline on a map. At the start the app draws a line all over the place (where the gps trys to gain an accurate location). Is there any way to tell that the location is accurate and therefore start drawing.

i thought count and if statement that after say 5 location updates start- but should the user have a strong location then my app will fail.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the CLLocation objects passed to your CLLocationManagerDelegate's

```
locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation
```

method; they have, among other things, 2 properties available: horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy.

They describe the radius of error, measured in meters.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocation/horizontalAccuracy